# How many times do I stringify JSON before sending to my JAVA Program

Tags: java, node.js, json, or-tools

I am calling a Java program that I wrote to solve VRP using Google OR Tools and I am calling that program from my Node JS file using child-process. Currently I am having to Stringify my data thrice to get the expected output and yesterday I was only having to do it twice with the same code in both Node and Java. My concern lies with the fact that what if I have to Stringify my data four times tomorrow. Is there a better way to Stringify data that is consistent every time or am I doing something wrong?

I have multiple JAR files all of which are returning the same responses when stringified once or twice but work fine when stringified thrice.

NODE JS CODE :-

```
const childPorcess = exec('java -jar <PATH_TO_JAR_FILE> ' + JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(data))), function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  console.log(JSON.parse(stdout))
})
```

HOW I PARSE IN JAVA :-

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(args[0]);
```

MY JSON OBJECT :-

```
{
  "locations": [
    [30.795288, 76.750204],  [-30.795061, 76.811813], [30.746093, 76.844772],   [30.783321, 76.952143],   [31.102846, 77.021502],
    [32.154861, 76.138451],  [31.083183, 76.516518],  [30.147566, 76.061848],   [31.866464, 77.586482],   [32.286318, 78.988468]
  ],
  "demands": [
    0, 1, 1, 3, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 1
  ],
  "vehicleCapacities" : [
    40, 40
  ],
  "vehicleNumber" : 2,
  "depot"         : 0
}
```

EXPECTED RESPONSE :-

```
"droppedNodes": [],
        "Vehicle 2": [
            0,
            1
        ],
        "Vehicle 1": [
            0,
            7,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            6,
            8,
            9,
            5
        ],
        "Total Distance": 129
```

ERROR RECEIVED WHEN I Stringify once or twice

```
Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (l) at position 1.
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
After having discussed this with several people, the comments and some professionals it seems that the problem is being caused by the OS (I was using Windows). After using it in mac OS it worked after making minor adjustments. We are now using the following way to exec the jar file

```
response.data = await exec(`java -jar <PATH_TO_JAR> '${JSON.stringify(requestBody)}'`);
```

This still only works in Mac OS and we haven't checked it on Linux but for Windows I'm still having to stringify it thrice.

Thank you to everyone in the comments for your support!

Comment: When you are sending your stringified JSON object to JAVA pgm, are you getting any errors? If there is you can add that in your question code. Also, how are you handling this data in your JAVA code?

Comment: I am not experiencing any errors. I am making an api call which invokes my nodeJS function that stringifies and call my java program's main class which then parses the data using JSONParser

Comment: If you are not experiencing any errors why are you stringify JSON thrice? It seems unclear in question why are you doing this if you are not getting an error?

Comment: Once is all you need to call `JSON.stringify()`.  Just once.  If calling it just once is causing a problem, then you need to explain/show that problem so we can work on solving it.

Comment: When I stringify once I get the error
Unexpected character (l) at position 1
It only works when I stringify thrice

Comment: Then, you're doing something else wrong.  This takes simple debugging and a little problem solving.  Call it once and look at that output and put it in your question and then maybe we can help you.  Calling it more than once is a hack attempting to bury some other problem.

Comment: Actually, I'm guessing that you can't pass the JSON directly on the command line without escaping something because the OS is messing with it.  Why don't you write the JSON to a file yourself and then pass the file to your Java program?

Comment: @jfriend00 I initially tried to call my program by defining my json object in the same file. It was then that I realised I had to stringify it twice to make it work, although today I'm having to do it thrice

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right that I cannot pass JSON directly in the command line that's why I am stringifying it but what baffles me is that I'm having to do it thrice today while I was only doing that twice yesterday. I can't find a reasonable explanation to this and am worried that I might have to stringify it more in the future

Comment: Thanks for posting this. we had a weird bug very hard to debug, turns out we needed to json stringify twice on Windows